# Python regular expression with raw string prefix

Tags: python

I'm new with python and regular expressions.

I have this regular expressions and i don't know what is the purpose of this

```
r'(\d+)\.(\d*)'
```

all I know is it matches a digit from 0 to 9.

can anyone help me explain it?

thanks..

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches a string containing one or more decimal digits, followed by a decimal place, followed by 0 or more decimal digits - ie, a floating-point number. It returns the two strings of digits.

For example, if you try it on the string "123.456" it will return ("123", "456").

Comment: It's kind of strange though that although it allows numbers with zero decimals, the dot is required. I think `r'(\d+)\.?(\d*)'` would make more sense to catch floats.

Comment: (shrug) it matches python syntax; 0 is int, 0. is float.

Answer (score 1):

This looks for at least one digit (or more) followed by a decimal point and zero or more digits after it.

This [quick reference/cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)  might be helpful looking up the parts that make up regular expressions.

This is a very nice [Google video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4) on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html  read it up. It will definitely be more enlightening than any answer you get here. That though matches digits (1 or more) followed by a decimal point and some further numbers (0 or more)